# No value given for one or more required parameters - import Text to Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, csv, import

I would like to import a text file with this code into an Access 2007 database file:

```vb
Dim test As New cAccess
test.Connect()
test.Command.Connection = test.Connection
test.Command.CommandText = 
        "insert into kvks " &
        "select f1 as artnr, f2 as [lfdnr-kal], f3 as saln, f4 as suchbegriff, f5 as wert, f6 as eh " &
        "from [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=" & txtKvks.Text.Substring(0, txtKvks.Text.LastIndexOf("\")) & "].[" & txtKvks.Text.Substring(txtKvks.Text.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) & "]"
Dim start As DateTime = Now
test.Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But I get the error "No value given for one or more required parameters".

The text file is delimited with semicolon (`;`). At first I thought, it is because it recognises one line as a field because of the standard delimiter comma, and then of course the another fields are missing.

I inserted a schema.ini file too in the same directory, where the file is stored, but the same result.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential cause of this error is that when using a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) file with the Jet/ACE "Text" engine the `HDR=No` clause in the `[Text;...]` database specification is ignored.

So, for an existing table named [MyExistingTable]

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyExistingTable (
    id INT,
    firstname TEXT(255)
)
```

a text file named "toImport.txt"

```
1;Larry
2;Hank
3;Artie
```

and a "schema.ini" file

```
[toImport.txt]
Format=Delimited(;)
```

the command

```vb
cmd.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO MyExistingTable " &
        "SELECT F1 AS id, F2 AS firstname " &
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public].[toImport.txt];"
```

will fail because it will interpret the first line of "toImport.txt" as column names: `[1]` and `[Larry]`, instead of the default `[F1]` and `[F2]` that are assigned when no column names are included.

The easiest fix is to add `ColNameHeader=False` to the "schema.ini" file

```
[toImport.txt]
Format=Delimited(;)
ColNameHeader=False
```

You can also get more sophisticated and add complete column specifications into the "schema.ini" file (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details).

**Another possible cause:**

The error can also be caused by a "schema.ini" file that is saved with a UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark). The Jet "Text" engine pre-dates Unicode and only supports two character sets – "ANSI" or "OEM" – for *both* the data file and "schema.ini" file.

Comment: In the fact, I have headers in the csv file. So I corrected the sql syntax according: 'HDR=Yes' and 'select * '.I don't get now the above error message, but a new one: the inster into command has an unknown field name: 'ARTNR;LFDNRKAL;SALN;SUCHBEGRIFF;WERT;EH'. It seems, that the semicolon isn't recognised. Why?

Comment: You still need a "schema.ini" file with `Format=Delimited(;)` so the semicolons will be recognized as the field separators.

Comment: but I have this already

I have also an acces datatable with this fields: ARTNR, LFDNRKAL, SALN, SUCHBEGRIFF, WERT, EH.

I have a schema.ini file in the folder, where the csv file is located:

[KVKS_1H2_20141001.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
ColNameHeader=True

And I have this sql command:

"insert into kvks select * from [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=" & txtKvks.Text.Substring(0, txtKvks.Text.LastIndexOf("\")) & "].[" & txtKvks.Text.Substring(txtKvks.Text.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) & "]"

It should recognise the semicolon. What do I wrong?

Comment: In the first row of the text file check the name of the second field and make sure that it exactly matches the name of the corresponding field in the Access table. You've mentioned both `lfdnr-kal` and `LFDNRKAL` as names for that field. As for the Text engine not recognizing the semicolon as the field separator, I cannot recreate your issue. I just tried it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: this was, because I experimented, that may be the - could be a problem, but not

I have the right field names. It seems, that the delimiter isn't recognised.

Comment: Another idea: Make sure that your "schema.ini" file is *not* UTF-8 encoded with a BOM (byte order mark). Open it in Notepad, choose `File` > `Save As...`, and make sure that the "Save as type" is "All files (*.*)" and the "Encoding" setting is "ANSI".