# How to import text file into existing Access table using Visual Basic(button click) (Visual Basic 2015))

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, import, text-files

I know how to import text file data (delimited) into an Access table manually, but is there any function that enables a click of a button to make this job done in Visual Basic 2015?

Comment: Yes: with `DoCmd.TransferText`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067136/importing-a-text-with-separators-using-vba

Comment: A search for `[vb.net] import text file to access` turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451257 as the very first result. Please do at least a basic search here first before posting a new question.